# Printing a 3x4 Calendar in Java (issue with start days after Jan)

Tags: java, calendar

My goal is to print a calendar  (Jan Feb Mar, then Apr May Jun on a separate row, etc.) January is the only month that works perfectly. My issues are: the start Day of each month after January (if Jan ends on a Monday, Feb has to begin on a Tuesday), and the days on the last week of each month are not placed correctly. Another minor concern is the length of the code, it seems too long/redundant for what I am trying to do. And I am limited to selection structures, loops, and modules. Any help or tips are appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Assignment4
{
  public static int startDates(int day, int month)
 {
  //calculate start dates for Feb-Dec, Based on previous months end day,possibly dependant on lastDayM
//status: not working
int i;
int startDay = 7-day;
return startDay;
 }
public static int lastDayM(int month, int year)
{
//calculate last day for every month
//status: working 
int lastDay = 0;
if ( month == 1 || month == 3  || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 ||month == 12)
  lastDay = lastDay + 31;
else 
{
  if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
    lastDay = lastDay + 30;
  else 
  { // Test for leap year(simple leap year)
    if (year % 4 == 0)
      lastDay = lastDay + 29;
    else
      lastDay = lastDay + 28;
  }
  }
  return lastDay;
 }

public static void displayHeader(int month)
 {
//display the month headers in a 3x4 format
//status:working
switch (month) 
{
  case 1: 
    System.out.print("            January"); break;
  case 2:
    System.out.print("                         February"); break;
  case 3: 
    System.out.println("                       March"); break;
  case 4: 
    System.out.print("             April"); break;
  case 5: 
    System.out.print("                           May"); break;
  case 6: 
    System.out.println("                            June"); break;
  case 7: 
    System.out.print("             July"); break;
  case 8: 
    System.out.print("                           August"); break;
  case 9: 
    System.out.println("                        September"); break;
  case 10: 
    System.out.print("           October"); break;
  case 11: 
    System.out.print("                          November"); break;
  case 12: 
    System.out.println("                      December"); break;
  }
}

public static int displayWeek(int month, int weekn, int lastDay, int day)
{
//status: almost working for every case. Only issue is the last week
//display the months one week at a time
int startDay = startDates(day, month);
int d = 0;
switch (weekn)
{
  case 1:
  {          
    for (int b = 1; b <= day; b++) 
    {
      System.out.print("    ");
    }
    for (d=1;d<=7-day;d++)
    {
      System.out.print("   "+d);
    }
    if(month!=1)
      day=7-(d%7);
    break;
  }
  case 2:
  {
    for(d=8-day;d<=14-day;d++)
    {
      if(d<10)
      {
        System.out.print("   "+d);
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.print("  "+d);
      }
    }
    break;
  }
  case 3:
  {
    for(d=15-day;d<=21-day;d++)
    {
      System.out.print("  "+d);
    }
    break;
  }
  case 4:
  {
    for(d=22-day;d<=28-day;d++)
    {
      System.out.print("  "+d);
    }
    break;
  }
  case 5:
  {
    for(d=29-day;d<=lastDay;d++)
    {
      System.out.print("  "+d);
    }
    if(lastDay%7==3)
      System.out.print("                ");
    if(lastDay%7==1)
      System.out.print("                        ");
    break;
  }
}
return d;
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
//declaration
int i, row, col, j, year, day, month;
String yearstr, daystr;

//input
yearstr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a year: ");
year = Integer.parseInt(yearstr);

daystr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a day for Jan.1: 0-Su, 1-M, 2-M, etc.");
day = Integer.parseInt(daystr);

System.out.println("                                              "+year);


//display month names
for(j=1;j<=3;j++)
{
  displayHeader(j);
}
//week header
for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
{
  System.out.print("   Su  M   Tu  W  Th   F   S");
  System.out.print("   ");
}
System.out.println();
//display a row of 3 months
for(row=1;row<=5;row++)
{
  for(col=1;col<=3;col++)
  {
    displayWeek(col,row,lastDayM(col,year),day);
    System.out.print("   ");
  }
  System.out.println();
}
System.out.println();

//2nd set of months
for(j=4;j<=6;j++)
{
  displayHeader(j);
}
for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
{
  System.out.print("   Su  M   Tu  W  Th   F   S");
  System.out.print("   ");
}
System.out.println();
for(row=1;row<=5;row++)
{
  for(col=4;col<=6;col++)
  {
    displayWeek(col,row,lastDayM(col,year),day);
    System.out.print("   ");
  }
  System.out.println();
}
System.out.println();

//3rd set of months
for(j=7;j<=9;j++)
{
  displayHeader(j);
}
for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
{
  System.out.print("   Su  M   Tu  W  Th   F   S");
  System.out.print("   ");
}
System.out.println();
for(row=1;row<=5;row++)
{
  for(col=7;col<=9;col++)
  {
    displayWeek(col,row,lastDayM(col,year),day);
    System.out.print("   ");
  }
  System.out.println();
}
System.out.println();

//last set
for(j=10;j<=12;j++)
{
  displayHeader(j);
}
for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
{
  System.out.print("   Su  M   Tu  W  Th   F   S");
  System.out.print("   ");
}
System.out.println();
for(row=1;row<=5;row++)
{
  for(col=10;col<=12;col++)
  {
    displayWeek(col,row,lastDayM(col,year),day);
    System.out.print("   ");
  }
  System.out.println();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: In your code, is 1 January or February? Also, is 1 Monday or Tuesday?

Comment: 1 is January, and 0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday, etc.

Comment: I'm trying to read your code, but it's very confusing. `startDates()` exists, but it's never used . . .

Comment: Im sorry, I meant to delete that method, that was just an attempt to figure out the start days after Jan.

Comment: Okay. I ran the code, and it seems that every month starts on the same day of the week and does not always end on the right day. Are those the only errors you are getting?

Comment: Yes, everything else is fine.

Comment: Great. I'm almost done going through it.

Comment: Thanks you! I appreciate it

Comment: Sorry to say, this code isn't very clean or elegant making it hard to debug or enhance. You *might* want to start over and write the code in a cleaner way, one that has methods that simplify the code and that avoids a lot of the dirty brute-force and overly redundant code that you have.

Comment: I figured as much, but I am not very good yet at clean code as I am still taking my first intro to java course at university. Do you have any tips of ideas I can implement to make this code cleaner?

Comment: Plan the program out on paper before hand before committing code to IDE.  Write smallish testable methods and then test them. If you want to create a tabular structure, look up the best ways to do that, including use of either `String.format(...)` or `System.out.printf(...)`.

Comment: I cant use String.format(..) or printf because we did not cover that in class, but I can definitely work on my methods. Thank you.

Comment: @Asgore I finished my answer. Please mark it as correct and upvote it if it helped you, since it took a lot of effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several mistakes, and like you said, it has some redundant code.

In the `main` method, you repeat the code for each row four times. This takes up four times as much space, and increases the chances of making a typo. Instead, you can create a loop, `for(int row=0; row<4; row++)`, and just let the code repeat four times.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    //Get input
    int year = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a year: "));
    int day = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a day for Jan 1: 0-Sun, 1-Mon, 2-Tues, etc."));

    //Print year
    System.out.println("                                              " + year);

    //For each of the four rows
    for(int row=0; row<4; row++){
        //Display the Month headers
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            displayHeader(3*row + i);
        }

        //Display the Week headers
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            System.out.print("   Su  M   Tu  W  Th   F   S");
            System.out.print("   ");                
        }           
        System.out.println();

        //Display the rows of each month
        for(int week=0; week<5; week++){
            for(int month=0; month<3; month++){
                displayWeek(3*row + month, week, firstDayM(3*row + month, year, day), lastDayM(3*row + month, year));
                System.out.print("   ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();                       
    }
}
```

Notice that I changed the setup of your int codes so that 0=January, 1=February, and so on. I also changed the days of the week to the same format (i.e. 0=Monday, 1=Tuesday, etc.). Keeping it consistent is always good. I tweaked the `displayHeader()` method slightly to reflect this change.

```
public static void displayHeader(int month){
    //display the month headers in a 3x4 format
    //status:working
    switch (month) {
        case 0: 
            System.out.print("            January"); break;
        case 1:
            System.out.print("                         February"); break;
        case 2: 
            System.out.println("                       March"); break;
        case 3: 
            System.out.print("             April"); break;
        case 4: 
            System.out.print("                           May"); break;
        case 5: 
            System.out.println("                            June"); break;
        case 6: 
            System.out.print("             July"); break;
        case 7: 
            System.out.print("                           August"); break;
        case 8: 
            System.out.println("                        September"); break;
        case 9: 
            System.out.print("           October"); break;
        case 10: 
            System.out.print("                          November"); break;
        case 11: 
            System.out.println("                      December"); break;
    }
}
```

Your `lastDayM` method worked; I just simplified it and added a `firstDayM` method that finds the first day of the week, by starting from January 1st and counting up.

```
public static int lastDayM(int month, int year){
    //calculate last day for every month
    //status: working 
    if (month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 8 || month == 10)
        return 30;
    if(month == 1){
        if (year % 4 == 0){
            return 29;
        }
        return 28;
    }
    return 31;
}

public static int firstDayM(int month, int year, int janOneDay){
    int firstDayM = janOneDay;

    for(int i=0; i<month; i++){
        firstDayM += lastDayM(i, year);
    }

    return firstDayM % 7;
}
```

Your `displayWeek()` method is what I had to spend the most time looking at, since your algorithm didn't make much sense to me. Eventually, I added a parameter `firstDay` and made the method follow these steps

- **If it's the first week**, offset the calendar based on the day of the week the month starts on (from the parameter `firstDay`
- For each subsequent week, just add more numbers
- For the last week, only go until the `lastDay`; then offset as needed

  ```
  public static void displayWeek(int month, int week, int firstDay, int lastDay){
  //status: almost working for every case. Only issue is the last week
  //display the months one week at a time
  switch (week){
      case 0:
          for (int b=0; b<firstDay; b++) {
              System.out.print("    ");
          }
          for (int d=1; d<8-firstDay; d++){
              System.out.print((d<10 ? "   " : "  ")  + d);
          }
          break;
      case 1:
          for (int d=8-firstDay; d<15-firstDay; d++){
              System.out.print((d<10 ? "   " : "  ")  + d);
          }
          break;
      case 2:
          for (int d=15-firstDay; d<22-firstDay; d++){
              System.out.print((d<10 ? "   " : "  ")  + d);
          }
          break;
      case 3:
          for (int d=22-firstDay; d<29-firstDay; d++){
              System.out.print((d<10 ? "   " : "  ")  + d);
          }
          break;
      case 4:
          if(lastDay == 28 && firstDay==0){
              System.out.print("                        ");
              break;
          }
          for (int d=29-firstDay; d<36-firstDay; d++){
              if(d<lastDay+1){
                  System.out.print((d<10 ? "   " : "  ")  + d);
              }else{
                  System.out.print("    ");
              }
          }
          break;
  }
  }
  ```

Note also that while this is not part of the question you asked, your application won't work for months that span more than five weeks (such as this month, coincidentally).

Here is the final code, for reference:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Assignment4{   
public static int lastDayM(int month, int year){
    //calculate last day for every month
    //status: working 
    if (month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 8 || month == 10)
        return 30;
    if(month == 1){
        if (year % 4 == 0){
            return 29;
        }
        return 28;
    }
    return 31;
}

public static int firstDayM(int month, int year, int janOneDay){
    int firstDayM = janOneDay;

    for(int i=0; i<month; i++){
        firstDayM += lastDayM(i, year);
    }

    return firstDayM % 7;
}

public static void displayHeader(int month){
    //display the month headers in a 3x4 format
    //status:working
    switch (month) {
        case 0: 
            System.out.print("            January"); break;
        case 1:
            System.out.print("                         February"); break;
        case 2: 
            System.out.println("                       March"); break;
        case 3: 
            System.out.print("             April"); break;
        case 4: 
            System.out.print("                           May"); break;
        case 5: 
            System.out.println("                            June"); break;
        case 6: 
            System.out.print("             July"); break;
        case 7: 
            System.out.print("                           August"); break;
        case 8: 
            System.out.println("                        September"); break;
        case 9: 
            System.out.print("           October"); break;
        case 10: 
            System.out.print("                          November"); break;
        case 11: 
            System.out.println("                      December"); break;
    }
}

public static void displayWeek(int month, int week, int firstDay, int lastDay){
    //status: almost working for every case. Only issue is the last week
    //display the months one week at a time
    switch (week){
        case 0:
            for (int b=0; b<firstDay; b++) {
                System.out.print("    ");
            }
            for (int d=1; d<8-firstDay; d++){
                System.out.print((d<10 ? "   " : "  ")  + d);
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            for (int d=8-firstDay; d<15-firstDay; d++){
                System.out.print((d<10 ? "   " : "  ")  + d);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            for (int d=15-firstDay; d<22-firstDay; d++){
                System.out.print((d<10 ? "   " : "  ")  + d);
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            for (int d=22-firstDay; d<29-firstDay; d++){
                System.out.print((d<10 ? "   " : "  ")  + d);
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            if(lastDay == 28 && firstDay==0){
                System.out.print("                        ");
                break;
            }
            for (int d=29-firstDay; d<36-firstDay; d++){
                if(d<lastDay+1){
                    System.out.print((d<10 ? "   " : "  ")  + d);
                }else{
                    System.out.print("    ");
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    //Get input
    int year = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a year: "));
    int day = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a day for Jan 1: 0-Sun, 1-Mon, 2-Tues, etc."));

    //Print year
    System.out.println("                                              " + year);

    //For each of the four rows
    for(int row=0; row<4; row++){
        //Display the Month headers
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            displayHeader(3*row + i);
        }

        //Display the Week headers
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            System.out.print("   Su  M   Tu  W  Th   F   S");
            System.out.print("   ");                
        }           
        System.out.println();

        //Display the rows of each month
        for(int week=0; week<5; week++){
            for(int month=0; month<3; month++){
                displayWeek(3*row + month, week, firstDayM(3*row + month, year, day), lastDayM(3*row + month, year));
                System.out.print("   ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();                       
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will spend time studying this code to understand it and hopefully I will make less of these mistakes in the future. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: @Asgore You're welcome. Feel free to ask any questions.